# Зачем на AMD GCN используется не нулевой NULL

Tags: c, opencl

В описании [этого коммита](https://reviews.llvm.org/rL289252) сказано:

> In amdgcn target, null pointers in global, constant, and generic address space take value 0 but null pointers in private and local address space take value -1.

Зачем в [AMD GCN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_Core_Next) так сделано?

Comment: Я не знаю, что такое AMD GCN, но могу предположить, что, возможно,  в локальном адресном пространстве разрешен доступ по нулевому адресу. Поэтому для локального адресного пространства приравняли null указатель к значению -1.

Comment: Они там же пишут, что llvm считает null указатель равен нулю, что приводит  к некорректному коду. То есть, они исправляют багу llvm своим хаком.

Comment: Видимо, как уже сказал @VladfromMoscow, в графической памяти ([Graphics Core Next (GCN)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_Core_Next)) (локальное адресное пространство?) работать с нулевым адресом можно.

Comment: Никакого "не нулевого NULL" там не планируется. Не путайте null pointer value и `NULL`.

Answer (score 5):

Во-первых, значение нулевого указателя (null pointer value) по сути своей должно быть таковым, чтобы оно "указывало" на заведомо неиспользуемый адрес памяти. По-видимому в локальном адресном пространстве адрес `0x00000000` - вполне используемый адрес, т.е. подходящим внутренним представлением для null pointer он не является.

Во-вторых, обратите внимание на аккуратное и грамотное использование терминологии автором прилинкованного текста. Речь идет о "null pointer" и "null pointer value", а не о `NULL`. `NULL` в тексте не упоминается вообще.

Макро `NULL` - это *null pointer constant*. Его менять совершенно не нужно, да и нельзя. Он как был, так и остается именно *нулевым*, как того требует стандарт языка. Ненулевого `NULL` в языке С быть не может. Меняется только внутреннее представление *null pointer value* в локальном адресном пространстве. То есть меняется то значение, которое фактически получает указатель, которому присвоена *null pointer constant*. Неявная трансляция константного нуля в это внутреннее значение - задача компилятора.

Другими словами, после данного изменения код вроде `i32 addrspace(0)*p = 0;` для указателя в локальном адресном пространстве будет тихонько транслироваться компилятором в занесение значения `0xFFFFFFFF` в `p`. На уровне исходного кода исправлять нули на что-то другое не нужно.

Comment: Спасибо, исправил семантику своего последнего предложения. Было не понятно, что имеется в виду не макрос.

Comment: После прочтения третьего абзаца, сложилось впечатление, будто бы последовательность бит, представляющая `NULL` может быть только нулевой. Хотя это не так.

Comment: @wololo: О какой "последовательности бит" вы говорите? Null pointer constant (каковой является и `NULL`) - это rvalue. У нее нет никакого конкретного представления в памяти (если под  "последовательностью бит" вы имеет в виду это). `NULL` обязан быть строго и именно нулем и только нулем.  В С это либо нулевая целочисленная константа, либо таковая константа приведенная к `(void *)`. То есть да, впечатление у вас сложилось правильное:
в стандартном С `NULL` может быть только нулевым.

Comment: Что означает фраза "`NULL` обязан быть строго и именно нулем"?

Comment: @wololo: Она означает, что допустимыми определениями `NULL` в С являются либо целочисленное константное выражение со значением `0`, либо такое выражение, приведенное к типу `(void *)`. Других вариантов нет. То есть если реализация вдруг захочет сделать другое определение `NULL`, оно все равно будет обязано внешне вести себя как `0` или `(void *) 0`.

Comment: То есть термин, которым можно обозначить выражение `(void *)0` — это "ноль"?

Comment: Да, именно это я имел в виду в тексте своего ответа. А что вы имели в ввиду под "последовательностью бит" для `NULL`?

Comment: Под последовательностью бит я подразумевал некоторое конкретное представление в памяти... Но тут я, очевидно, был некорректен, ибо, как вы и написали "Null pointer constant (каковой является и NULL) - это rvalue". Попробую корректнее изложить то, что мне не ясно. Вы пишете, что NULL — это "ноль". Но что такое "ноль"? Можно ли назвать floating constant со значением `0.0` термином "ноль"?

Comment: Я не пытаюсь выработать строгую формальную терминологию, но тем не менее: да, можно. `0.0` это "ноль" типа `double`. Легальным NPC (null pointer constant) такой "ноль" не является. NPC, по определению, должен быть "нулем" целочисленного или указательного типа. Не всякий "ноль" есть NPC.

Comment: @AnT, Спасибо, что уделили время и прояснили непонятные моменты.

Answer (score 2):

Необходимо понять, что `NULL` не имеет никакого отношения к нулевому адресу. `NULL` - это лишь универсальное определение невалидного указателя.
Для того, чтобы понять, *почему* сделано именно так, нужно знать внутреннее устройство адресного пространства GCN.
Просматривая [whitepaper](https://www.amd.com/Documents/GCN_Architecture_whitepaper.pdf) GCN, можно найти следующее заявление:

> In tandem with cache coherency, GCN introduces virtual memory through
>   a combination of hardware and driver support. <...> More importantly, it
>   paves the way for a single address space that is seamlessly shared by
>   CPUs and GPUs.

Следовательно, адресное пространство в GCN является общим для CPU и GPU и можно предположить, что нулевой адрес является валидным адресом для данной схемы. Если это так, то значение невалидного указателя не может быть нулевым, чтобы не совпадать с валидным адресом в памяти.